# Detect orientation when loading a view

Tags: objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation, ios-universal-app

I'm developing a universal app.
When my device is ipad I have 2 designs: Portrait and landscape.

I use this method:  `-(void)orientationDidChanged:(NSNotification *)notification`

It works perfectly when I rotated my device. But I have a problem, when first load the view  and I have not rotated the device.
   For that reason, I put this code in the viewdidload:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){ //
     something.
}
else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    NSLog(@"IPAD ** ");
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
        NSLog(@" vertical ** ");
    }
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)){
         NSLog(@"Horizontal ** ");
    }
}
```

My problems is this: sometimes it works , sometimes not :(. This method: orientationDidChanged, when start to work? only if I rotate my device or immediately with the viewDidLoad , is necessary ask one more time the orientation when I have that method? Thanks for some advice.

I don't have problem when I rotated my device, it works perfectly :D .. My problem is when I recently run the application and I haven't  turned the device

Comment: I want to know  why mark my question like negative, I would appreciate if you let me know. I'm learning english and I think that my question is clear,  I don't have problem when I rotated my device, somebody tell me what I did wrong!

Comment: I have to write well my question, but you need to read well my problem, somebody delete your answer, :( I don't understand how works it!

Comment: I solved with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382937/how-do-i-detect-an-ipads-interfacerotation-at-the-start

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if(orientation == 0) //Default orientation 
    //UI is in Default orientation (Portrait)
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    //UI is in Portrait orientation
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    //UI is in Landscape-left orientation
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    //UI is in Landscape-right orientation
```